# Trigger 2 spring integration in different server but with 1 same file polling folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using `int-file:inbound-channel-adapter` to process the file.

I got 2 `int-file:inbound-channel-adapter` in 2 difference server but polling same folder.

2 listener will listen to 1 same server folder. Listener 1 not able to process the message because it had been processed by listener 2. Errors shown as below.

Listener 1 :-

```
2014-12-20 22:15:27.608 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Added to queue: [/folder/101.txt]

2014-12-20 22:15:27.715 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler@502a3135 received message: [Payload=/folder/101.txt][Headers={timestamp=1419084927715, id=f5bb68b3-0eac-40a6-8fcf-8ba54fc295af}]
2014-12-20 22:15:27.724 [task-scheduler-3] INFO  org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler - Failed to move file '/folder/101.txt'. Using copy and delete fallback.
```

Listener 2 :-

```
2014-12-20 22:15:27.585 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Added to queue: [/folder/101.txt]

2014-12-20 22:15:27.711 [task-scheduler-6] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler@1447034b received message: [Payload=/folder/101.txt][Headers={timestamp=1419084927710, id=2177d3cd-fbd9-4412-98d1-48ce84874b53}]
```

So what i suspect is the initiate both of the listener's payload message got the file. But after 1 of the listener processed the file already, second listener unable will hit error.

Part of the code like below:-

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="Id1" directory="/folder" prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:outbound-gateway 
    request-channel="Id1" reply-channel="Id1Processing"
    directory="/folder/backup}" delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Appreciate someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: you don't want to process the same file on the second server to avoid that error. For this purpose you should use [`FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/files.html) as a reference to the `filter` of the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Consider to use some out-of-the-box `MetadataStore` or implement your own one.

Comment: Currently code is using acceptOnceAuditTrailSelector to filter processed file in DB. Because would like to process same filename if there is any error. Can show how to implement this FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter?